# VPS ONLY allow people acess to garrys mod gameserver AFTER connecting through ssh or acessing a service on the server somehow

Tags: linux, networking

I have got a pretty strage issue, which is persistent through different reinstalls of the VPS and even when I switch distros (I switched from Ubuntu 18 to 16 and then to CentOs 7. All had the same or simmilar issues, however I have only confirmed all the details I am going to talk about on CentOS and its also what the server is running right now).

My server currently runs CentOS 7 and on it there is a standard webserver and a garrys mod gameserver.

Everytime a person tried to connect the ingame console was used with the appropriate ip and command.

The ports are definitely open and working. I have verified with external tools and the server recognizes them as open.

The problem:

To confirm the specifics of the problem I have had a few friends run an experiment on it. Here are the results.

NOTE: Trying to join repeatedly DOES NOT fix the issue. I have verified this multiple times and the only way people were able to connect was after doing the things I mentioned below.

**Person A:**
Person A is me. I was able to connect immediately after setting up the server using ssh.

**Person B:**
Person B is a friend of mine. He was not able to connect and I didnt conduct any further experiments due to time limitations he had.

**Person C:**
I had Person C try and connect without success. However he asked for access to ssh and after providing it and him messing around in the server, but after ultimately changing nothing but restarting the server once he tried again and was able to join. After that he was always able to join without accessing ssh ever again.

**Person D:**
With Person C now being unlocked I wanted to find out what happend. The only common line between Me and Person C seemed that we both acessed the server using ssh. I had Person D try again to connect to gmod without any success. After that I instructed him how to download putty and ssh into my server. I asked him to leave SSH immediately after and then asked him to try and connect to the server. Worked.

**Person E:**
This is where I was still confused. I thought that maybe connecting to ssh would whitelist the ip from connecting. If that was true, however, the following WOUDLNT have worked. 
To test the issue further I thought of some other service I could have people connect to. The easiest would be a webserver I thought, however I never expected it to work. Installing the  normal webservice in CentOS 7, I asked Person E to help me out. Again, verifying that he couldnt connect before, I asked him to visit the website hosted on my server. He wasnt able to load the website for some reason, but after attempting to join gmod it instantly let him through.

**Person F:**
I attempted the same thing as with Person E, however Person F was able to load the website and join the server after. Again before loading the website he wasnt able to join, even after trying 2-3 times with restarting the game and me restarting the server.

The servers console also didn't react to any connection attempts before attempting to connect through ssh or webserver and trying again. Other gameservers seem to be working fine, however further testing is required.

**This lead me to conclude the following:** People are only able to connect to the gameserver when they access some other service located on the same machine.

**What I think it might be** Maybe the server provider has some sort of security feature that only allows certain applications to work. If that is true it also seems to whitelist any ip(s) that connects through a "trusted service". this is a pure guess and my provider hasn't responded to any of my inquiries.

This doesnt seem to be a gameserver specific problem, since the games support is completely stumped as well and I wasnt able to fully confirm any other gameservers working, since I havent had the time and people to test it on other games.

Even if this cannot be solved, it seems like an interesting mystery after all.

Comment: SSH is a red herring. You have not provided enough detail about your network or router/routing to allow for a meaningful answer.

Comment: @davidgo this is a hosted vps. I do not know anything about the router setup they are using.

Comment: The VPS system fingerprint could be stored somewhere by the initial SSH access, and re-used by the game app, which is otherwise unable/unwilling to get it from an unknown system.

Comment: @xenoid thank you for you answer but I actually managed to fix it about 5 minutes ago. I am going to post the solution as self answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

After waiting for/fighting with support for a long time and doing some more testing, we found out that the server I recieved was one of the first ones to have a new DDOS-Protection system. The port my server was using was not in the "trusted" port list and therefore every ip that tried to connect through it was blocked. I havent gotten any more info from them other than that. I assume connecting to a service on a "trusted" port temporarily whitelists the ip. This is just a guess though.

Sorry for the quite unsatisfying end to this question.
Thanks everyone who tried to help